# Data formatting for 1D-CNN in R

Tags: r, keras, conv-neural-network

I have an array of data (around 1000+ cases (rows), and about 650+ columns of information (V1 - V5 in the example below) which I want to use for a keras 1D-CNN (which has 3 classifications (class in the example below)).

I'm having trouble trying to format the data in a way that will fit the model that I have written.

The data looks similar to this:

```
set.seed(999)
case <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H')
class <- c('N','N','T','R','T','R','N','T') 
V1 <- runif(8, min = 0, max = 1)
V2 <- runif(8, min = 0, max = 1)
V3 <- runif(8, min = 0, max = 1)
V4 <- runif(8, min = 0, max = 1)
V5 <- runif(8, min = 0, max = 1)

df <- data.frame(case, class, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)
df
```

The keras 1D-CNN I have written is this:

```
build.model <- function() {

  model <- keras_model_sequential()

    model %>%
      layer_conv_1d(
        filter = 32, kernel_size = c(5), padding = "same",
        input_shape = c(100, 3)
      ) %>%
      layer_activation("relu") %>%
      # Use max pooling
      layer_max_pooling_1d(pool_size = c(2)) %>%
      # Flatten max filtered output into feature vector
      # and feed into dense layer
      layer_flatten() %>%
      layer_dense(128) %>%
      layer_activation('relu') %>%
      layer_dense(3) %>%
      layer_activation('softmax')
 
    model %>% compile(
      loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
      optimizer = 'rmsprop',
      metrics = 'accuracy'
    )
  return(model)
}

model <- build.model()
print(model)
```

When I try to pass the df through the model it doesn't work.
I know it's to do with the format of the data, but I'm at a loss as to how to rectify this.

Any tips/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

TIA
Miki

Comment: You need pass data as a matrix, not a data frame. Also you model is configured to accept input tensor of shape [n,100,3] which i do not think it what you want to do. You probably need to set `input_shape = 5` (numbers of columns). Also while you will do CNN with filter 5 you will get one column out of 5, then max pooling will collapse (for pooling you would need at least 2 columns). Finally i personally do not think that is good idea to broaden units from 1 to 128 in the middle of the network.

Comment: And why use CNN in the first place? You can imagine CNN filter as some kind of moving average, which is not always a good idea to do to your features.

Comment: Hi @Miki Parr, did you able to solve the problem?

Comment: It's been a while, but safe to say I solved this by using the matrix and not a data frame. :)